# SQL: Conditions in grouped data

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
(row)  | date        | transaction  | articleno  | salesamount
==============================================================
(1)    | 2017-01-01  | 1            | A          | 1.0
(2)    | 2017-01-01  | 1            | B          | 2.0
(3)    | 2017-01-01  | 1            | C          | 2.0
(4)    | 2017-01-01  | 1            | null       | 0.0
--------------------------------------------------------------
(5)    | 2017-01-02  | 2            | X          | 1.0
(6)    | 2017-01-02  | 2            | Y          | 2.0
...
```

I want to make a SQL statement which goes through my table and looks for **baskets/groups** (identified by `date` and `transaction` combination), that have both

- a row where `salesamount` is `> 1.0` (e.g. row 2 and 3) **AND**
- another row where `articleno` is `null` (e.g. row 4)

within the same basket (**not only in one row**). I need to give back the `date/transaction` combinations that fulfill the conditions above. In the example table above, the first group would be relevant and `2017-01-01 & 1` should be returned.

I tried to use the `having` condition after a `group by date, transaction` but this seems not to be able (`having` can only be used for columns or aggregations that refer to the columns of the `group by` clause).

How can I do this? Do I need an inner SQL?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM (
    SELECT date,transaction
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE salesamount > 1.0  
    GROUP BY date,transaction
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT date,transaction
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE articleno IS NULL
    GROUP BY date,transaction
) t2
ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.transaction = t2.transaction
```

Comment: Yes, that did it for me! Thank you!

Comment: You're Welcome .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, transaction FROM yourtable WHERE salesamount > 1.0 AND articleno is NULL
```

Comment: `articleno = NULL` will not work. You need `articleno is NULL`

Comment: This would only return rows which have both conditions in the same row. But I have to check one condition in one row of the group, and the other one in another row (of the same group).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query(Assumed Oracle Database).

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date,'YYYY/MM/DD'), transaction
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE article is null
AND salesamount > 1.0
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(date,'YYYY/MM/DD'), transaction
```

Comment: This would only return rows which have both conditions in the same row. But I have to check one condition in one row of the group, and the other one in another row (of the same group).